# Como deixar essa função javascript generica

Tags: javascript, funções

Tenho essa função abaixo e gostaria de deixar ela genérica, pois os valores de `innermap`, `-125,127` e `3` vão variar.

Em vez de ficar criando várias funções: `centralizar()`; `centralizar1()`; etc., eu gostaria de deixar apenas uma função e ir passando apenas os parâmetros para as próximas funções onde serão diferentes os valores.

Como fazer isso?

```
function centralizar() {
    innermap.flyTo([-125,127], 3);
}
```

Comment: Olá Isa! A resposta abaixo resolveu seu problema? Dá um feedback pra gente. Obrigado!

Comment: @Isa A resposta resolveu seu problema? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 9):

Usando parâmetros

```
function centralizar(innermap, a, b, c) {
  innermap.flyTo([a, b], c);
}
```

Ou talvez usar um *array* ao invés de `b, c`. Chutando os parâmetros sejam coordenadas e *zoom*, ficaria

```
function centralizar(map, coords, zoom) {
  innerMap.flyTo(map, coords, zoom);
}
```

<sup>[**Dica do bfavaretto nos comentários.**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257978/como-deixar-essa-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-javascript-generica/257979#comment529643_257979)</sup>

[Documentação de funções](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: Não falto o 4 parametro q ela pediu "innermap" que seria um (a,b,c,d) ?

Comment: se for alterar o nome da função pode fazer `var nomedafuncao ='innermap'; window[nomedafuncao](a,b,c)`

Comment: Eu faria `centralizar(map, coords, zoom)` – chutando que o terceiro é zoom.

Comment: Olá! Primeiro, não se estresse, é um debate normal. Se eu enviar `centralizar('qualquercoisa', '-125,127', '3')` sua função vai funcionar?

Comment: @ÐvÐ Não porque os dois parâmetros (`a, b`) são números pra formar o _array_ e não uma _string_. Deveria ser **`centralizar('qualquercoisa', -125, 127, '3')`**. E acho que não entendi a primeira frase.